# How to see the exact "views" on a question

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question on SU that has 1k views. Now, I would like to know if there is a way for all question over 1k to see the exact of views that question got. I think that adding a little button or if we click on "1k" just like when we checked up/down votes on a question, that we can see the total of views.

We could have like a standard of operating for all "hidden information"...

Hope this question is at the good place and is accurate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just hover your mouse over the "1K" and a tooltip will show the actual count.

Comment: In deed, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 8):

You can also click through to the post, the exact view count is shown in the sidebar:

> asked
>   **today**
>
> viewed
>   **8 times**
>
> latest activity
>   **today**